# debug loop to extract years for each amod extraction in dependency parsed file (bash)?

Tags: bash

**Problem**: The below code is not outputting any data in the files (that it is successfully creating in the output folder)? See code and example of input file below.

- I know the grep -oP part is correct on line 12 as I tested it in my console.
- The problem started when I added the loop to extract years relating to the amod, so think the issue might be with grep -P and how the file is formatted. I assume it might be having trouble getting years associated with each adjective modifier (amod).

/////////////////////

```
  2 psych_corpus="/data/projects/punim0322/Processed/abstract_year_journal.csv.DEP.part"
  3 cohacoca_corpus="/data/projects/punim0322/COHACOCA/coha.coca.processed.all.lc.no-numb.noacad.DEP.part"
  4
  5 word="men|women"
  6 output_dir="output"
  7
  8 for w in $(echo "$word" | tr "|" "\n")
  9 do
 10     for digit in $(seq 1970 2018)
 11     do
 12         (grep -P " \|\|\|\|\| $digit \|\|\|\|\|" "$psych_corpus" | grep -oP " '[[:alpha:]]+:ADJ:amod:${w} '" | sort | uniq -c |\
 13         awk -v year="${digit}" -v OFS=',' '{print year, $2, $1}') >> "${output_dir}/amod_${w}_${psych_corpus##*/}"
 14     done
 15 done
 16
```

/// CORPUS EXAMPLE ///

intervention:NOUN:pobj:of ,:PUNCT:punct:interventions problem:NOUN:compound:solving solving:NOUN:compound:training training:NOUN:conj:interventions ,:PUNCT:punct:training the:DET:det:process interpersonal:ADJ:amod:influence influence:NOUN:compound:process process:NOUN:conj:training ,:PUNCT:punct:process and:CCONJ:cc:process future:ADJ:amod:research research:NOUN:conj:process .:PUNCT:punct:discussed ||||| 1988 ||||| journal_old ||||| journal_new

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Please remove line numbers from your code in your question.

Comment: That is some terrifying data. Is is really all on one line? or can you wrap the display at `;`s and use the `code/data/output/errMsgs` font? Good luck

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Yes that is the data as there are 100k lines of it.

Expected output is: 

```{r} 
year, w:ADJ:amod:$w, count 
1980, white:ADJ:amod:man, 5
```
I can get the file to give output when I am not also trying to extract years, which makes me think it is when I try to get the years for each count that the problem arises. My error file is also not giving clues which is strange.

Comment: Pleaset edit your question and add the expected output inside a codeblock.

Comment: `psych_corpus` and `cohacoca_corpus` are defined but only the former is used in the code shown.

Comment: `grep -oP " '[[:alpha:]]+:ADJ:amod:${w} '"` does not match anything in the corpus example you provided - (1) neither "men" nor "women" appears as value for `$w`; and (2) corpus contains no single-quotes

Comment: Thanks @jhnc! That was it. I needed to remove the single quotes and only have "" for the regular expression.